# issue with excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I am trying to write a formula for example, that when I copy and paste it, It will grab the same column but always add 39 to the row. I'm trying to process some information.

For example formula:

='XYZ Summary'!L153 (I would like to always add 39 so instead of 153, its 193)

So I used absolute reference for the column (It kept defaulting to column W instead of L):

='XYZ Summary'!$L153

But now I don't know how to make it so it will add 39 each time.

If anyone could help me out, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the value from the cell that is 39 rows down from cell A1.

```
=OFFSET(A1,39,0)
```

This formula can be put in cell A1 or in another cell, providing the row is not fewer than 39 rows from the bottom of the sheet. For example, putting that formula in cell `A1048572` will return `#REF!`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fixed number; you could hard code it in the formula `=XYZ!$L1+39`. But better solution will be to use fixed cell `=XYZ!$L1+$A$1`. So you could see the actual value and change it if needed.

Comment: Your formula is adding 39 to that value in cell XYZ!$L1, this is not what the OP asked.